# How to share variables across components in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope, ionic2, angularjs-service, ionic-tabs

In Ionic 1 (With Angular 1), I can create a `$scope.abc` on the ngApp layer and other ngControllers can inherit `$scope.abc` with ngModel, so that when a text area in one controller changes, the others will change accordingly via ngModel.

**How may I achieve "synchronized text area" with Ionic 2 (and Angular 2)?**

Here are some of my attempts:

1. Injecting MyApp in the constructor of the components: the `[(ngModel)]="myApp.abc"` will result in a undefined error in console of failing to resolve context.myApp.abc...
2. Creating a Service with a setter. Use [(ngChange)] to call the setter and use getter in the constructor of another component: the text area doesn't change after the component is instantiated.  Using ViewOnInit instead of Constructor doesn't help either.  Is there an event handler for "component is shown on screen"?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! :) You can use [this starter plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TqCYx0?p=info) (by clicking fork) to include your code and then adding that link to your post so we can play around with it. Please also consider taking a look at the new Documentation section where you can find some tutorials related to Ionic2 like [this one about services](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ionic2/4407/using-services#t=201608131423243511083).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a service and add this service to the shared parent component (or if there isn't one, add it to app component's) list of providers. Make sure to import the service in each component that needs to use the service. Then inject the service in constructor of each component that needs it.

Plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/l3BlNdjQfzPIIGPSXp9n?p=preview

```
// >>>home.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Component1 } from "./component1.ts";
import { Component2 } from "./component2.ts";

import { YearService } from "./year.service.ts"
@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html",
  directives: [Component1, Component2],
  providers: [YearService]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() {   }

}

// >>>home.html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <comp-one></comp-one>
  <comp-two></comp-two>
</ion-content>

// >>>component1.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { YearService } from "./year.service.ts";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./component1.html",
  selector: "comp-one"
})
export class Component1 {
  constructor(yearSvc: YearService) {   
    this.year = yearSvc.getYear();
  }
}

// >>>compnent1.html
<p> Year from component 1 using a shared service: <strong>{{year}}</strong></p>

// >>>component2.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { YearService } from "./year.service.ts";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./component2.html",
  selector: "comp-two",
})
export class Component2 {
  constructor(yrSvc: YearService) {
    this.year = yrSvc.getYear();
  }
}

// >>> component2.html
<p> Year from component 2 using a shared service: <strong>{{year}}</strong></p>

// >>> year.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class YearService {
  getYear() {
    return new Date().getFullYear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user1275105.  I have figured out how to do my job after reading your answer ;)
As I have mentioned in the post (though without clearly stated in the title, my mistake), I would like to achieve _synchronized_ textarea.  For people looking for an answer, it will be to inject `yearSvc` in constructors of the components, and put `[(ngModel)]="yearSvc.year"` in the textareas.

Comment: Yes. The main point is to use service to share date between components. Also remember NOT to add service in the components own providers if  your intention to share data. If you want each component to have its own instance of service then add service to each component providers. Example where this matters is in situation where your service has a 'total' variable being incremented from within the component. Here you need to ensure service is added to the parent component's provider.